# How can I make one method for adding records in all tables?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

How can I stick to DRY principle with my problem? I have many methods adding records to tables. But all look the same and only types of objects are changing. Therefore I copy and paste a lot of code. Here is one of them:

```
public IEnumerable<MyClass> GetMyClassRecordsWithLastVersion()
{
   var records = _context.DataTable.ToList();
   // Get all records with the highest Version. 
}
```

I add records from this method but with increased `Version` and `Id`:

```
public void AddMyClassRecords(IEnumerable<MyClass> recordsToAdd)
{
   var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
   {
      cfg.CreateMap<Type, Type>();
   });

   ...

   foreach (var record in recordsToAdd)
   {
      var newRecord = mapper.Map<MyClass, MyClass>(record);
      newRecord.Version = record.Version + 1;
      newRecord.Id = maxId + 1;

      ...

      _context.DataTable.Add(newRecord);
    }
    ...
}
```

Other methods look the same but with different `Type` (e.g. `MyClass1`, `DataTable1`). I tried to pass `Type` and `DataSet` as parameter. Then use it like `_context.*DataSetFromParameter*.ToList()` and `mapper.Map<TypeOfMyClass, TypeOfMyClass>` but didn't succeed.

Comment: `_context.Set<T>().Add()`?

Comment: what @CodeCaster says is right, but it lacks a bit of explanation. You should look into [generic types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) this way you can make a base service. And implement this wherever you want to add, get or set values in the database

Comment: @Roe [`Set<T>()` is a method on the DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.set?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontext-set-1) which does exactly what the OP wants. No need to add a base service or generic type here.

Comment: Once again you are right, except you don't explain what T stands for in your example. It is a generic type which might be unclear to new programmers. To clear it up `T` is replaced by the type matching the table you are trying to access.

Comment: Thank you guys, I didn't know a lot about generic types in c# and now I have much to learn ;)